# How to change attr on condition using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    [data-Status = "Used"]{
        background-color: green;
    }

    [data-Status = "Inactive"]{
        background-color: red;
    }

    [data-Status = "Active"]{
        background-color: gray;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="Changestatus('Combo_1')" id="Combo_1" />
    <div class="Combo_1 Activity_1" id="Activity_1" data-Status="Active">Activity_1</div>
    <div class="Combo_1 Activity_2" id="Activity_2" data-Status="Active">Activity_2</div>
    <div class="Combo_1 Activity_3" id="Activity_3" data-Status="Active">Activity_3</div>
    <div class="Combo_1 Activity_5" id="Activity_5" data-Status="Active">Activity_5 C3</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="Changestatus('Combo_2')" id="Combo_2"/>
    <div class="Combo_2 Activity_1" id="Activity_1" data-Status="Active">Activity_1 C1</div>
    <div class="Combo_2 Activity_3" id="Activity_3" data-Status="Active">Activity_3 C1</div>
    <div class="Combo_2 Activity_4" id="Activity_4" data-Status="Active">Activity_4 C3</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="Changestatus('Combo_3')" id="Combo_3"/>
    <div class="Combo_3 Activity_4" id="Activity_4" data-Status="Active">Activity_4 C2</div>
    <div class="Combo_3 Activity_5" id="Activity_5" data-Status="Active">Activity_5 C1</div>
    <div class="Combo_3 Activity_6" id="Activity_6" data-Status="Active">Activity_6</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to change attribute of common activity on checkbox check

**For Example**

I checked **Combo_1** so this **data-Status** change into **Used** and other combos common activity **data-Status* should change into **Inactive** if i uncheck this Combo then all common **[data-Status=Inactive]** should change into **[data-Status=Active]**;

**This Code i have written and it works but is there any easiest way to do that**

```
function Changestatus(element){
    var Active_Class = $('.'+element);
    if ($('#'+element).prop("checked") == true) {

        for(var i = 0; i < Active_Class.length; i++){
            if ($(Active_Class[i]).attr("data-Status") == 'Active') {
                $(Active_Class[i]).attr("data-Status", "Used");
            };
        }

        $('.'+element).each(function() {
            var elem_id = this.id;
            var Active_ID_Class = $('.'+elem_id);
            for(var i = 0; i < Active_ID_Class.length; i++){
                if ($(Active_ID_Class[i]).attr("data-Status") == 'Active') {
                    $(Active_ID_Class[i]).attr("data-Status", "Inactive");
                };
            }

        });
    }

    else if ($('#'+element).prop("checked") == false){

        for(var i = 0; i < Active_Class.length; i++){
            if ($(Active_Class[i]).attr("data-Status") == 'Used') {
                $(Active_Class[i]).attr("data-Status", "Active");
            };
        }

        $('.'+element).each(function() {
            var elem_id = this.id;
            var Active_ID_Class = $('.'+elem_id);
            var Used_Activiy = false;

            for(var i = 0; i < Active_ID_Class.length; i++){
                if ($(Active_ID_Class[i]).attr("data-Status") == 'Used') {
                    Used_Activiy = true;
                };
            }
            if (Used_Activiy != true) {
                for(var i = 0; i < Active_ID_Class.length; i++){
                    $(Active_ID_Class[i]).attr("data-Status", "Active");
                }
            };

        });
    }
}
```

**At least select two combo to understand my question**

Comment: Ids must be unique `Activity_1`, `Activity_3`, and `Activity_5` pairs are invalid.